# What's wrong in this "logo"?

Tags: logo, critique, color-spaces

I'm trying to do a logo for myself, just to put it in my apps.
I just drawn (by hand) my Surname-Name, flipped the name vertically, added a background as you can see.

I know that usually there is a "theory" about colors and shapes. I have some doubts: for example, what changes into the watcher's eye if the text would be white? Is it too complex to be defined a "logo"? What can I do to make it more interesting for the eye?

[image]

Comment: One of the first questions you should ask yourself is: If this was printed in one color, at 1 inch wide and I squint, can I make sense of it?

Comment: It lacks readability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two **very** basic benchmarks for a logo:

- If it has text, can you read it?
- If it made of shapes, can you draw
  it from memory?

The problem with your logo really is that it has no unique shape that makes it distinguishable other than handwritten text, which we can't read. So you you are killing off your own benefit. And the color boxes (which are from the first kuler page, really) do not convey any message on their own. So your logo is left with saying *nothing*. Which is the opposite of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll surely think about that!
Just another question: how would you judge "Paul Smith" logo according to the factors you listed?

Comment: "Paul Smith" is a pseudo-handwriting with the benefit of being readable.   They also use the colors a bit differently, mainly as infinite background, making us see it as part of their corporate design but not part of the logo.

Answer (score 0):

Few questions you can think over:

- The logo is using brush or handmade?
- Text used inside is signature of anyone?
- Is this readable?

The Logo:

- Logo is represents company brands or corporate identities in market.
- Logo should be simple and creative.
- Easy to read, relevant text can be added.

Solution you can go for:

- Change the text of Logo as it is gangling and ungraceful.
- Why you used the dark color background? Use bright colors, the dark color varnishes the glow of upper text.

Hope this helps to improve your Logo.